# How to format code based on a selected code structure?

Tags: java, html, ide, formatting

I'd like to know how to format my code, using Notepad++, Eclipse, or other free IDEs to where it will be more readable, including color formatting, but more importantly, indenting, auto-removing of trailing/leading space & chars/etc. What is the quickest (language-independent) IDE and method of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

almost all the latest editors supports formatting. i.e. IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse ....

On Eclipse use CTRL+SHIFT+F or in the main menu > Source >.

Further you can change the the way you want to format in preferences.

Comment: The files always open in my default browser/IDE for that specific language. If I change the default app to launch and read the code in Eclipse, will this work for all langs?